# Gradually adding rectangle animation in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift4, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation

I have a single view application in Xcode and doing the following in ViewController.swift. My objective is to have the screen filled up with a brown colored rectangle gradually over 5 seconds. Am I missing something or is the approach completely wrong?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let expandAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    expandAnimation.fromValue = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0))
    expandAnimation.toValue = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
    expandAnimation.duration = 5.0
    expandAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    expandAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    let rectLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    rectLayer.fillColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor
    rectLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0)).cgPath
    rectLayer.add(expandAnimation, forKey: nil)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(rectLayer)
}
```

I don't want the color to gradually appear. I want a glass filling kind of effect. Imagine this

[image: Water Filling Fancy]

except for the fancy wavy effects.

Comment: You want to have your view gradually changing it's color from a color to another color ?

Comment: From empty to completely filled with brown color

Comment: I need this wavy effect water filling, please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After understanding your question better, you want to simulate the filing of a water glass (without the animation of the wave), you can achieve that through:

```
    let myLayer: CALayer = .init()
    myLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)

    func animateFilling(to view:UIView)
    {
        var mFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 0)
        myLayer.frame = mFrame
        let fillingAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
        fillingAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        fillingAnim.fromValue = mFrame
        fillingAnim.duration = 2
        fillingAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        mFrame.size.height = 1000
        fillingAnim.toValue = mFrame
        myLayer.add(fillingAnim, forKey: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Sorry If I was not verbose enough in my explanation. But I don't want the color to gradually appear. I want an opposite of a glass filling kind of effect. Imagine the opposite of [this](http://i1.wp.com/www.quartzcodeapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/water-fill-animation.gif?resize=300%2C300) except for the fancy wavy effects. Which is why I was using `UIBezierPath`

Comment: Thanks for doing a quick response though!

Comment: Cool, update your question with this gif, will make clearer for people.

Comment: @AbSin no problem, I have edited the answer based on your new explanation.

Comment: This doesn't give wave animation on top

Comment: @Sh_Khan see question, the filing effect is the one required only not the wavy effect.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I think wave animation is more trickier than just getting this in place. Will give it an attempt, I am still learning if I can't do it will post a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easy to do it like that if you don't want top wave

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let vv = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 0))

    vv.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

    self.view.addSubview(vv)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {


         vv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.size.height / 3.0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height * 2 / 3.0)

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks it does the job too!